# How to rename JQXwidget tree node

Tags: javascript, jqxwidgets

I use Jqx tree to create a tree. But i was unable to rename added Node to the tree, could some one please help me to do this. http://www.jqwidgets.com/

I was try to do some thing like this, but it wont work
`var selectedItem = $('#jqxTree').jqxTree('selectedItem');
selectedItem.label='Node 3'

$('#jqxTree').jqxTree('render');`
This will assign new name to node, but tree is not refresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rename it by using the "updateItem" method.

See the Update button's code here: [jQWidgets Tree](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxtree/settings.htm?arctic)